# Give keywords a rank

Tags: php

The title is really bad but I'm unsure how to describe what I'm looking to achieve... Basically, my website is sent lots of user input and I'm looking to create a score from keywords in a sentence made by the user. 
 For example; 
Comment - `This video was trash I can't believe you would upload something like this` 
`video` = 5 `trash` = 8 `was` = 6 
Due to the phrase containing keywords the sum returned is 19 
 So far I've tried using a lot of `strpos` if statements but they don't stack up if the word is repeated, so then I decided to use `substr_count` and just multiply the number but that was a problem for smaller words that are within other words... I'm just curious if there is a better way to do this? Just a way to have a word list with each word equal to a score... Thanks in advance and sorry if this doesn't make much sense but I've struggled to describe this.

Comment: use explode to separate the words by spaces into array elements and then your task will be much easyer

Comment: Yes, split into single words, then you can use array_count_values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest doing a explode to separate the words, then do a loop, something along those lines:

```
$string = 'This video was trash I can\'t believe you would upload something like this';
$key_words = array(
    'video' => 5,
    'thrash' => 8,
    'was' => 6
);
$score = 0;
$exploded_string = explode(' ', $string);
foreach($exploded_string as $substr){
    if($key_words[$substr]){
        $score += $key_words[$substr];
    }
}
```

Comment: By any chance can you put two worded phrases for example 'this video' instead of just 'this' and 'video' into the array.?.?

Comment: and say a user says videos it won't count the word? is there anyway around that??

Comment: The string is actually separating the words by the whitespace, so cases like 'this video' won't work, unless we find another way other than separating the words

Comment: To be honest, both your questions could be answered using the substr_count function, but it would count the words within words you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Explode on space in order to get an array of all the words
2. Filter out empty values that can occur due to multiple spaces
3. Call $occurrences = array_count_values($words);
4. Multply with word value

Untested:

```
$values = array("video" => 5, "trash" => 8);
$str = "This video was trash";
$words = explode(" ", $str);
$occurrences = array_count_values($words);

$total = 0;
foreach($values as $word => $value) {
  if(isset($occurrences [$word])) {
    $total += $value * $occurrences [$word];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You planning to to get scores directly from comment, then I would recommend using `preg_match()`.

```
$comment_string = 'some_comment_string video = 4 was : 6 thrash = 9';
$ratings = [
    'video' => 0,
    'thrash' => 0,
    'was' => 0,
];
$sum = 0;

foreach($ratings as $search=>$value){
    preg_match('#' . $search . '\s*[:|=]\s*([0-9]+)#', $comment_string, $match);

    if(isset($match[1])){
        $ratings[$search] = $match[1];
        $sum += $match[1];
    }

}

// do anything with $ratings array OR
echo $sum;
```

With regular expression, You have more control over string. Like accepting `=` or `:` as delimiter between score name and actual value. Also `\s` allows to ignore spaces.
Please consider separate inputs for each property, that users rates.